# Is there something wrong with the way this thing is connected?

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I have this mosfet connected to motor, to control it (on / off).
I use 5V arduino signal to do that, but motor doesn't spin.
I connected the grounds, checked motor and transistor - they work. What could be the problem here?
[image]

Update: MOSFET does not work with 5V, even though it should according to datasheet's threshold voltage (which is 4V)
Update 2 : it works just need to put mosfet after load

Comment: We already have a question showing the correct layout at [How does this MOSFET based motor driver designed work](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/493967/how-does-this-mosfet-based-motor-driver-designed-work) please also see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330999/nooby-cant-control-a-dc-brushed-motor-with-a-mosfet-please-help for some things you need to take into account when selecting the NFET.

Comment: Name, I see you may not be familiar with customs and practises on SE. Please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation for people making answers to your questions. Should none of the answers below fully satisfy your original question, please leave a comment to seek clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You've created a "source follower" circuit with the motor connected between source and 0 volts. The maximum voltage you will see will be about 3 volts across your motor and, as a result, it is unlikely to spin very fast.

A much improved circuit is the "common source" circuit where the MOSFET source is connected to 0 volts and the motor is connected between drain and +12 volts. With the right MOSFET you'll be able to get over 11 volts onto the motor but, the motor has to be capable of working with a ground connection (most will of course).

Answer (score 0):

First I recommend you check the gate voltage, because maybe the arduino cannot to active the gate. I've made an upload of a very simple circuit to use a MOSFET as switch ON/OFF connected an DC motor. Furthermore, I would use an optocoupler to activate the MOSFET Gate and ensure the gate will receive a correct voltage to work. Using the Opto you can use, for example, 12VDC, without any problems.

[image: On/off circuit diagram using mosfet as switch. Source: Adapted from: https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/topic/1251814-mosfet-como-chave/]

Source: Adapted from: https://www.clubedohardware.com.br/topic/1251814-mosfet-como-chave/

Comment: yes, I tried simpler example with 12V led and it didnt work with 5V. But 12V works. I dont understand. Gate threshold voltage is 4V max. So 5V should be enough? I am using IRF3205. Does gate has to be same as drain? Because when I tried small led with 5V it work both for drain and gate...